# LAS sample file for electric utility poles

Tags: lidar

Does anybody know a souce where I can find a sample LAS file that has electric utility poles?
Like seen here - http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//015w00000040000000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I keep lidar for all of virginia. Yes we have the files at http://www.wm.edu/as/cga/VALIDAR/index.php

Comment: this is great, thanks.  lots of good samples here.

Comment: no problem, coll topo website for lidar http://www.opentopography.org/

Comment: And after particular amount of time, it's already 404

Answer (score 1):

The state of Ohio/OGRIP has a GIS web map which you can zoom in, select, and download las datasets:

[OGRIP Data Downloads](http://gis5.oit.ohio.gov/geodatadownload/)